# Controlar un string

Tags: c#, string

Tengo una consulta con respecto a controlar un string de tal forma que el contenga 3 letras y 3 números
es para controlar una contraseña de 6 dígitos

Comment: puedes utilizar una expresión regular te dejo esta que busca 3 letras minusculas y tres numero   ^[a-z]{3}\d{3}$

Comment: podrias mirar [ask]?? que intentaste??? que problema tuviste???

Comment: @EnriqueAsensio tu expresión regular no es suficiente debido a que obliga a que el string tenga las 3 letras al principio y los 3 números al final.

Comment: Yo no te di ninguna respuesta. Trato de preguntar que es lo que hiciste y que problema tuviste, si no, tu pregunta da a interpretaciones donde vas a tener un monton de respuestas inconclusas porque no sabemos tu escenario real. Esta clase de preguntas suelen ser mal puntuadas por dicho movito.

Comment: Super importante revisar  [ask] para que realices tus preguntas de forma adecuada en el sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo mediante System.Linq

```
    // WWW999 - TRUE
    // TEST10 - FALSE
    // PRUEBA - FALSE
    // 11DD11 - FALSE
    // 2PL69N - TRUE
    // 9D9E9W - TRUE
    // 35KKK1 - TRUE

    using System.Linq;

    private bool IsValidPassword(string password)
    {
        return password.Count(c => Char.IsDigit(c)) == 3 && password.Count(c => Char.IsLetter(c)) == 3;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasar el arreglo por un bucle que termine cuando lea los 6 caracteres, y usar la función `Char.isLetter(caracter, indice)` y `Char.isNumber(caracter, indice)` y luego registras la cantidad de letras y numeros que tienes para luego evaluar si `numeros==3 && letras==3`, el bucle seria de la siguiente manera:

```
for (int i = 0;i<6;i++){
   if (Char.isNumber(tustring, i)){
      numeros++;
   }
   if (Char.isLetter(tustring, i)){
      letras++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, recuerda que es importante responder preguntas que sean realizadas en base al documento [ask], para que la informaciòn sea de ayuda no solo al que pregunta si no a toda la comunidad, saludos.

Answer (score -2):

Lo mas simple y genérico que puedes hacer es usa una expresión regular para esta validación esto en c# sería algo así como:

```
bool esValida;
string contraseniaAValidar = "123ABC";

Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z]{3}\d{3}$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
esValida = regexObj.IsMatch(ContraseniaAValidar);
```

Dependiendo si `esValida` es `true` o `false` tu contraseña habrá o no cumplido con la condición que mencionas

Comment: Tu expresión regular no es suficiente debido a que obliga a que el string tenga las 3 letras al principio y los 3 números al final, y aunque la pregunta no es muy específica, al parecer se refiere a que la contraseña "contenga" 3 letras y 3 números sin importar el orden.